# Declaring a struct in a separate golang package cannot return value, but it can when declared specifically

Tags: function, pointers, go, struct, package

Trying to import a struct type from another package, and it returns perfectly, but the values of that struct can't be found unless declared without the use of an instantiation function.

```
// X executes and finds values fine, Z does not.

package main

func main () {

    x := &Command{}
    z := command.NewCommand()

    fmt.Println(x.command)
    fmt.Println(z.command)
}
```

```
package command

type Command struct {
    // Our structured data/object for Command
    alias   string
    command string
    verbose bool
}

func NewCommand() *Command {
    // Creates a new container for []Command objects
    return &Command{"","",false}
}
```

What exactly am I missing here...?

Comment: Is this the whole source? You should be importing the `command` package in main somehow in order for this to work.

Comment: How do `X` and `Z` relate to `x` and `z`?

Comment: X is x and Z is z (if you read the code), they are in different folders and the imports declaration isn't here. as it is irrelevant to showing the problem in a practical manner.

Comment: Please make sure the example above actually reproduces the problem you're seeing. Your example is missing imports, the reference to Command is missing the package, and the fields of the command struct are unexported so you would be unable to access them from either invocation. It's unclear to me what the problem you are describing is, and since the example code is broken I can't run it to try and find out. The import is most certainly relavant to showing the problem; we can't reproduce your problem without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant [golang spec](
https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) is:

> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another
>   package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case
>   letter (Unicode class "Lu"); and the identifier is declared in the
>   package block or it is a field name or method name. All other
>   identifiers are not exported.

Since your struct fields are not capitalized, they do not qualify to be exported to another package. In order to fix this, you need to capitalize the fields you would like to access externally.

It might look something like this:

```
type Command struct {
    Alias   string
    Command string
    Verbose bool
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your struct fields needs to be capital for it to accessible outside the package.

```
type Command struct {
  // Our structured data/object for Command
  Alias   string
  Command string
  Verbose bool
}
```